# In vb.net, how to change the color of each individual point of a point or line chart

Tags: vb.net

After adding a new point, I try to set its color, but it doesn't work:

```
dim point_index = MONEY_Chart.Series( "profitability").POINTS.ADDXY( event_timestamp_DATETIME, Yvalue )
MONEY_Chart.Series( "profitability").POINTS( point_index ).color = Color.Green
```

I want different color depending on Yvalue.

Comment: I added a chart to a form and used this code: `Chart1.Series.Clear()` `Dim s = New Series()` `s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point` `Dim n = s.Points.AddXY(1, 1)` `s.Points(n).Color = Color.Red` `n = s.Points.AddXY(2, 2)` `s.Points(n).Color = Color.Green` `Chart1.Series.Add(s)`. It coloured the points as expected. Do you have some other settings for the series which might be interfering with colouring the data points?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I just had to figure out the same thing ... How to change the color of a single point on a Chart control in VB.NET. So far most have said it cannot be done with the current control .. PHOOEY !
I just tried this line of code with a chart that I write 40 data points to.
Worked like a charm !

```
MyChart.Series(0).Points.Item(any point number here).Color = Color.MediumPurple
```

Wish I had figured this out this years ago ...

Comment: Just to add to my new found discovery here ... I just wrote a second line of code same as above to see if you can have different colors for each point and it works. I ran the program and I have a red point and a purple point on a 40 point chart ... the other 38 points are not colored.